# Array to tree structure

Tags: javascript, data-structures, antd

```
[
    [
        "zhejiang",
        "hangzhou2"
    ],
    [
        "zhejiang",
        "hangzhou",
        "a",
        "a1"
    ],
    [
        "jiangsu",
        "nanjing",
        "zhonghuamen"
    ],
    [
        "zhejiang",
        "hangzhou",
        "a",
        "a2"
    ],
    [
        "zhejiang",
        "hangzhou",
        "a",
        "a3"
    ]
]
```

Hi everyone, im using ant design's cascader and it returns selected values in array structure like above.

As you can see, each value is the parent of the subsequent value. I need to convert above structure to the below structure, so i can use it in antdesign's tree component. I tried so many ways but i just couldn't do it.

```
[
       {
          "title":"zhejiang",
          "key":"zhejiang",
          "children":[
             {  
                "title":"hangzhou2",
                "key":"hangzhou2"
             },
             {
                "title":"hangzhou",
                "key":"hangzhou",
                "children":[
                   {
                      "title":"a",
                      "key":"a",
                      "children":[
                         {
                            "title":"a1",
                            "key":"a1"
                         },
                         {
                            "title":"a2",
                            "key":"a2"
                         },
                         {
                            "title":"a3",
                            "key":"a3"
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
          ]
       },
       {
          "title":"jiangsu",
          "key":"jiangsu",
          "children":[
             {  
                "title":"hangzhou2",
                "key":"hangzhou2"
             },
             {
                "title":"nanjing",
                "key":"nanjing",
                "children":[
                   {
                      "title":"zhonghuamen",
                      "key":"zhonghuamen",
                   }
                ]
             },
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the path of titles and build an object if not exist.

```js
const
    data = [["zhejiang", "hangzhou2"], ["zhejiang", "hangzhou", "a", "a1"], ["jiangsu", "nanjing", "zhonghuamen"], ["zhejiang", "hangzhou", "a", "a2"], ["zhejiang", "hangzhou", "a", "a3"]],
    result = data.reduce((children, path) => {
          path.reduce((object, title) => {
              let item = (object.children ??= []).find(q => q.title === title);
              if (!item) object.children.push(item = { title, key: title });
              return item;
          }, { children });
          return children;
      }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will scrutinize the code and make sure I understand.

I wish i could write this my own, I hope one day i can write my own solutions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all paths with the same prefix, then generate subtree for that prefix:

```js
function treeify(items) {
  const lookup = {};
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.length) {
      const [first, ...rest] = item;
      (lookup[first] ??= []).push(rest);
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(lookup).map(key => {
    const node = { title: key, key };
    const children = treeify(lookup[key]);
    if (children.length) node.children = children;
    return node;
  });
}

const items = [["zhejiang","hangzhou2"],["zhejiang","hangzhou","a","a1"],["jiangsu","nanjing","zhonghuamen"],["zhejiang","hangzhou","a","a2"],["zhejiang","hangzhou","a","a3"]];
const tree = treeify(items);
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but it returns.

'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keys')'

second answer (from Nina) solved my problem BUT If you can fix it I would like to review your code and learn something new.

Comment: That is very strange; when you click "Run code snippet" you get an error? If so, what browser are you using? If you are getting that error with some other data than the data you posted above, what is that data? Please supply the [example] that demonstrates the error.